# Convert C# Event and Delegate to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

This is my C# Code

```
public void Subscribe(string QueueName, string ActiveMQHost)
{
 consumer.Listener += new MessageListener(OnMessage);
}

private static void OnMessage(IMessage message)
{

}
```

I want to convert above code to vb.net.
Please Help.Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248087/how-to-convert-this-c-sharp-event-delegate-code-into-vb-net-2008-or-2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Public Sub Subscribe(ByVal QueueName As String, ByVal ActiveMQHost As String)
    AddHandler consumer.Listener, AddressOf OnMessage
End Sub

Private Shared Sub OnMessage(ByVal message As IMessage)

End Sub
```